# what could it be the purpose of this kind of decleration?

Tags: javascript, performance, reverse-engineering

The below code is from google analitycs api. I can imagine some of the purpose is for encrypting the script and some is for lowering the file size. But i thing there is more of these. What could it be the purpose of this kind of decleration but these?

```
var g = void 0, 
i = !0, 
j = null, 
k = !1, 
aa = encodeURIComponent, 
ba = Infinity, 
fa = setTimeout, 
ga = decodeURIComponent, 
l = Math;
function ha(a,b){
    return a.name=b
    }

var 
m = "push",
ia = "test",
ja = "slice",
o = "replace",
ka = "load", 
la = "floor",
ma = "charAt",
na = "value",
q = "indexOf",
oa = "match",
pa = "port",
qa = "createElement",
ra = "path",
r = "name",
t = "host",
u = "toString",
v = "length",
w = "prototype",
sa = "clientWidth",
x = "split",
ta = "stopPropagation",
ua = "scope",
y = "location",
va = "search",
z = "protocol",
wa = "clientHeight",
xa = "href",
A = "substring",
ya = "apply",
za = "navigator",
B = "join",
C = "toLowerCase",
D;
```

Comment: For obfuscation and for reducing code size, is pretty much all that comes to mind. If any other reason(s) found, pls share here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those variables can be used to dynamically create javascript variable names.
Plus the kind of varaibles choosen (one or two letters only) will shorten the code.

Update: Example:

```
var 
  m = "push",
  ia = "test";

for(i=0;i<100;i++)
  eval("var " + ia + i " = \"my_value\";");
```

Comment: It does make sense, but can you show an example, where using variables for keywords is employed?

Comment: An example drawn from the list of the OP would be: `fa[ya](null,[fun,100]);`, which would be a shortened form of `setTimeout.apply(null,[fun,100]);`

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a Google service they're using the Closure Compiler to minify JS files. Closure does its best to squeeze everything in as small a space as possible.

For example, since `j === null`, you can now say `x=j` instead of `x=null` (saves 3 characters).

The declarations themselves are optimized as well, so some of them might look a bit unintuitive:

```
void 0 === undefined
!0 === true
!1 === false
```

As for the strings, I suspect they're used to shorten calls to object methods (`x[m]()` instead of `x.push()`, saves 2 characters).